# Where to set the layout globally in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to implement the master page asp.net concept in my MVC application, when googled I could understand that the same can be obtained by using layouts in MVC. 
 I have _Layout file in my application under ~Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml. 
To have the content in layout file in my employee detail page I have added the following to

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayEmployeeList";
}
```

I wanted to know, if I have repeat the above piece of code in all pages individually or can I do it globally somewhere so that its viewable at all pages.

Comment: `_ViewStart.cshtml` it is !

Comment: @AthibaN added in ViewStart.csHtml nothing happnes

Comment: keep a break point in the line `return View()` in your Action and press F11 repeatedly.. you will see the control going into `_ViewStart.cshtml`

Comment: Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_layout.asp) for more info

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.. The reason was I have added the file and named as ViewStart.cshtml instead of _ViewStart.cshtml.

Comment: Good to know it helped, Mark this thread as answered if your problem is solved, @Serv's solution is more detail..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can set it for all pages at once.

In your Views folder, there should be a `_ViewStart.cshtml`

Just refer the _Layout.cshtml there and all your views inherit from this.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Further explanation from Scott Guthrie:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx

and directly from asp.net:
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application

**/EDIT:**

If you want to bring some logic to the ViewStart you can (for example) check if the request comes from a mobile device and therefor use another Layout:

```
@{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MobileLayout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```